# Sample size for a survey with randomly assigned questions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sample-size, survey, sample

This may seen like a dumb question for someone familiar on how to structure survey sample sizes, but I have a hard time finding the literature to back this up.

I have a survey that cover's 3 countries, US, UK and Canada, which has the following flow:

1. Out of a list of 100+ items, person is showed a sample of 20 to be selected
2. Out of the selected items, 2-3 are selected for further elaboration
3. For each of further elaboration, respondent is shown 17 items and is asked to select 3

Think of this as:

- Q1: How important it is for you go to the supermarket?
- Q2: Out of this 20 items (random out of a list of 100+ items), which ones have one bought last time you went?
- Q3: For this item 1 that you selected, which of this 17 reasons led you to buy it?
  Repeat Q3 for 2-3 items

As you can see, there is a funnel of questions and potential items selected to a respondent. Essentially there are >5k items combinations that can be shown to a participant.

From that survey, we aim at achieving two goals:

1. Measure average "score" values that come out from stage 1 above
2. Compare populations (Male vs Female, <25y vs >25y, etc.) for the 5k item combination

Given all that the question is: What should be our sample size and how should we assign the questions?

Problem is, when I look at comparing populations we are normally talking about hypothesis tests, that can have as little as 30 data points, but when talking about to represent these populations then there is a lot more data that is needed.

I don't think anyone we will have a clear answer on this, but given this situation, what are the considerations and the approach I should take to find the ideal sample size?

Comment: This question looks too vague to answer.  Could you (1) explain what a "score" is and (2) tell us the objective of this survey without relying on its current design?  That would help us understand what you are trying to do and evaluate how well this design might achieve that, both of which are essential for addressing the question of sample size.

Comment: Sure! A score is a ordinal variable that the respondent can select. Think of it as "how do you rate the importance of X on a scale from 1-10?"
The goal of the survey is to measure this scales on the population level (e.g. what would be the average score for the US?) and measure differences between intersections of the populations (e.g. is there a significant different between male vs female?)

Comment: I"m sorry, but I am unable to connect that with the description in your post: how exactly are the "2-3 ... for further elaboration" and "17 items" and "select 3" related to this goal?

Comment: Think of this as:
Q1 -> How important it is for you go to the supermarket?
Q2 -> Out of this 20 items (random out of a list of 100+ items), which ones have one bought last time you went?
Q3 -> For this item 1 that you selected, which of this 17 reasons led you to buy it?
Repeat Q3 for 2-3 items

Then I want to make an assessment of Q1 for a geography and compare this between groups, but also compare the reasons proportions between groups

Comment: The example is so helpful that I would like to suggest including it in the post itself.